# How to get java regex working from properties file?

Tags: java, regex, groovy, properties

When reading dynamic regex search and replace values, b.e from properties, java jre may not working always properly. How to get it working well with \ chars?

```
String search = props.getProperty("search", null);
String replace = props.getProperty("replace", null);
String strResult = strText.replaceAll(search, replace);
```

(Java regex usually is working well with literal regex.)

Comment: Are there regexes in that property file, or simple strings that you want to use for search / replace? If it is regexes that you have in the property file, your code should be fine, if the property file is written correctly. (i. e. the backslashes are escaped properly in the property file). Maybe it would help if you post the contents of your property file.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (to handle backslash \ chars well)

```
String groovy = "def String gregex = '" +search + "'; return gregex;";
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
Object result = shell.evaluate(groovy);
if (result != null && result instanceof String) {
    strData = strData.replaceAll(result.toString(), replace);
}
else
    strData = strData.replaceAll(search, replace);
```